# how to take user repositories from several pages of github

Tags: java, json, github-api

Here is my code.

1. Can I somehow provide a url so that the program checks all sites with repositories? The point is that I want data from page = 1, page = 2, page = 3 to be downloaded at once. Maybe there is a general form for all pages?
2. There are 30 repositories on page 1 and 2 and my program from page 1 and 2 only downloads 29. From page 3 sometimes 5 sometimes 6 repositories but there is 6 repositories. Why?

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=30&page=1";
    String data = readUrl(url);
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("name") + " : " + jsonObj.get("updated_at"));
    }
}
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

}

EDIT
With this lines application i returning 65 of 66 repos.

```
    String url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=1000";
    String url2 = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=1000&page=2";
    String url3 = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=1000&page=3";

    String data1 = readUrl(url1);
    String data2 = readUrl(url2);
    String data3 = readUrl(url3);

    JSONArray jsonArr1 = new JSONArray(data1);
    JSONArray jsonArr2 = new JSONArray(data2);
    JSONArray jsonArr3 = new JSONArray(data3);


    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr1.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr1.getJSONObject(i);

        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("name") + " : " + jsonObj.get("updated_at"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr2.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr2.getJSONObject(i);

        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("name") + " : " + jsonObj.get("updated_at"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr3.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr3.getJSONObject(i);

        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("name") + " : " + jsonObj.get("updated_at"));
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you increase the query parameter `pagelen` to a very big number, e.g. `pagelen=1000`

Comment: nothing, all the time he returns the result of 29/30 repositories from the first page

Answer (score 1):

Github search requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. In most cases you can increase the number of items per page to a maximum of 100 using `?per_page` parameter. So your search request url should be `https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?per_page=100&page=page_no`. See [Github pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) .